# How to get a ext2 super blcok in linux kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am working with the linux kernel of android 6.0, where kernel version is 3.10. Now I mount a sdcard(file system of it is ext2) to it. Which function should I use if I wanna get the super block of this sdacrd? Is it sget in /fs/super.c?

```
struct super_block *sget(struct file_system_type *type,
        int (*test)(struct super_block *,void *),
        int (*set)(struct super_block *,void *),
        int flags,
        void *data)
```

Comment: If you want to **mount in kernel space** (weird thing, actually), use `do_mount()` function. This function is called from `mount` system call, which implementation you may find by grepping kernel sources for 'SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount'.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean I wanna find the super block refering to the ext2 file system

Comment: So you need to read bytes from the device *directly* (not as a part of *filesystem*). Then interpret bytes read as ext2 super block structure (you may copy-paste definition of this struct from sources of ext2 driver. `struct super block` is meaningless for your purpose - it corresponds to the **mounted** device.